# How to change the cassandra.yaml file and restart cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I have cassandra cluster with three nodes. Currently it configured as no authentications for login.
**`authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator`**

I need to change the configuration as below.

```
**authenicator: PasswordAuthenticator
authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer**
```

In order to apply them I need to do a restart. How can I restart the cluster. To apply above setting should I change the all cassandra.yaml files on all three nodes. OR Is it enought to change only one? Should I restart all three nodes on by one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the settings on all nodes and restart one after each other.

Depending on how and where you run your cluster/ nodes, it could be /etc/init.d/cassandra restart or restart of the pods.

Comment: I installed these instances by tar ball. How do I find the which process id in order to kill?

Comment: ps aux | grep cassandra